# Baffling permissions failure when starting Apache

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server

I am setting up a fresh installation of Apache2 on Ubuntu 18.04, but Apache won't start. The error I get:

`(2)No such file or directory: AH00089: Couldn't start ErrorLog process '/usr/bin/cronolog /var/log/apache2/log_my_domain/error.log'.
AH00015: Unable to open logs`

Here's the relevant line in my conf:

`ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/log/apache2/log_my_domain/error.log"`

Apache starts fine when my site is not enabled, and I have confirmed that it's running as user `www-data`.

Here are my log permissions:

```
/var/log:
  drwxr-xr-x   4 root      www-data           4096 Jun 16 18:17 apache2

/var/log/apache2:
  drwxr-xr-x  4 root www-data 4096 Jun 16 18:17 .
  drwxrwxr-x 12 root syslog   4096 Jun 16 06:25 ..
  -rw-r-----  1 root www-data    0 Jun 15 00:09 access.log
  -rw-r-----  1 root www-data 1796 Jun 16 19:22 error.log
  drwxrwxr-x  2 root www-data 4096 Jun 16 19:15 log_my_domain

/var/log/apache2/log_my_domain:
  -rwxrwxr-- 1 root www-data    0 Jun 16 19:15 error.log
```

Comment: It turned out that I fixed the permissions problem, but then received a very similar looking error whose root was that I didn't have `cronolog` installed.